# Why my for loop is running one extra iteration in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

I am trying to run the following simple code in R but the for loop runs one extra iteration and I am not able to figure out the reason behind it. Could you please help me with that?

```r
fun <- function(x) { 
  y <- as.character(0)
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] == "NO") {
      y[i] <- c("Its a NO")
      y <- append(y, y[i])
    } else if (x[i] == "YES") {
      y[i] <- c("Its a YES")
      y <- append(y, y[i])
    } else {
      y[i] <- c("Don't know")
      y <- append(y, y[i])      
    }    
  }
  return(y)
}

a <- c("YES","NA", "NO")

fun(a)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to initialize 'y' as the `length` of 'x' and then remove the `append`

```r
fun <- function(x) { 
  y <- character(length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    y[i] <- if (x[i] == "NO") {
      c("Its a NO")  
    } else if (x[i] == "YES") {
      c("Its a YES")        
    } else {
      c("Don't know")
    }
  }
  return(y)
}

a <- c("YES","NA", "NO")

fun(a)
#[1] "Its a YES"  "Don't know" "Its a NO"
```

Answer (score 2):

For loops in R run from start to end inclusive.

```
for (i in start:end)
```

Change it to:

```
for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
```